# Creating a custom bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

This is what my widget tree essentially looks like (without the boilerplate)

```
PageController pageController = PageController();


return Column(
  children: [
    PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      children: [
        Navigator(onGeneralRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(context) {
          return Screen1(); // has AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
        }),
        Navigator(onGeneralRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(context) {
          return Screen2(); // has AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
        }),
        Navigator(onGeneralRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(context) {
          return Screen2(); // has AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
        }),
      ],
    ),
    // bottom bar
    Row(
      children: [
        Button(onPressed: () => pageController.jumpToPage(0), "1"),
        Button(onPressed: () => pageController.jumpToPage(1), "2"),
        Button(onPressed: () => pageController.jumpToPage(2), "3"),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

This works fine for the most part. The problem is, there are more routes that I go to on each of the Screens.

The behaviour I want is for each of the Screens to reset (go back to initial view) if I press the same bottom bar item again.

Possible solutions?

1. Some kind of function in Screens that recognizes when PageView updates with new screen (not sure if this is a thing) and then I could use a parameter in each of the Screens that orders them to go back to initial view (with `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(etc..)`)
2. Any other solution that you might now

Thanks!

Edit: I don't want to use a pre-existing widget or package

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current page and then perform routing like

```dart
 Button(onPressed: ()  {
   if(pageController.page!.toInt()! = 0)  
       pageController.jumpToPage(0), "1");
    }
```